# Using python to read data (associated with variables) from MS Word

Tags: python, ms-word

total newbie with Python.
I have many Word docs that have textboxes. Using VBA I have captured the text in those boxes to variables. As a start, I would like to be able to open each Word doc in a given folder, read each of the VBA variables containing the textbox data and print it to a text file.

I have Python 2.7.3 and have installed Pywin32.

Comment: This is probably going to be much harder than you'd expect. Parsing Word files is a complicated task on its own. You'd have better luck if you could discover (or describe) the method VBA uses to do what you want, and maybe read up on [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model)

Comment: There is absolutley no need - and indeed it would be an insane task - to parse the files in his own script.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go from where you are: use Python + COM to remote control your word application - that should bethe easier thing to do. The other way to have access to Word Data from Python is to write Python scripts to the LibreOffice suite - it is able to import MS-word files on its own, and it interfaces with Python. But it should be complicated to do that, as that interfacing is badly documented and used by few people.

Therefore, autmating ms-word is the easier way to go - check the examples here - they should get you started:
http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/view/158/192/